# Calculation with modular forms

Tags: calculus, modular-forms

Let $\Delta(z)=(2\pi)^{12} q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)^{24}$ with $q=e^{2\pi i z}$ be the modular discriminant.

I found $$\left(\dfrac{\Delta(6z)\Delta(z)}{\Delta(3z)\Delta(2z)}\right)^{1/2}=q\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-q^{6n+1})^{12}(1-q^{6n+5})^{-12}$$
and I don't understand why.

I get $$q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}((1-q^{6n})(1-q))^{12}((1-q^{3n})(1-q^{2n}))^{-12}.$$
Is that the same?

Thanks.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your question. See my answer.

Comment: Why did you edit the question to remove the specific function whose product form is desired? I have done rollback to the previous version.

Comment: Because the equation was wrong as you said. It is maybe better if there are no mistakes in the question for others.

Comment: Ok. It would be better to add one line indicating that the equation mentioned in question appears wrong and a correct equation is desired. If you remove the expression $$\left(\dfrac{\Delta(6z)\Delta(z)}{\Delta(3z)\Delta(2z)}\right)^{1/2}$$ from the question then the whole context is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $q^{n}$ corresponds to $nz$. Hence we have
\begin{align}
F(q) &= \left(\frac{\Delta(6z)\Delta(z)}{\Delta(3z)\Delta(2z)}\right)^{1/2}\notag\\
&= \left(\frac{q^{6}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{6n})^{24}\cdot q\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{n})^{24}}{q^{3}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{3n})^{24}\cdot q^{2}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{2n})^{24}}\right)^{1/2}\notag\\
&= q\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(1 - q^{n})(1 - q^{6n})}{(1 - q^{2n})(1 - q^{3n})}\right)^{12}\text{ (you have reached till this point)}\notag\\
&= q\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(1 - q^{n})(1 - q^{6n})}{(1 - q^{2n})(1 - q^{3n})}\right)^{12}\notag\\
&= q\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1 - q^{2n - 1}}{1 - q^{3(2n - 1)}}\right)^{12}\notag\\
&= q\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1 - q^{2n - 1}}{1 - q^{6n - 3}}\right)^{12}\notag\\
&= q\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(1 - q^{6n - 1})(1 - q^{6n - 3})(1 - q^{6n - 5})}{1 - q^{6n - 3}}\right)^{12}\notag\\
&= q\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\{(1 - q^{6n - 1})(1 - q^{6n - 5})\}^{12}\notag\\
&= q\prod_{n = 0}^{\infty}\{(1 - q^{6n + 1})(1 - q^{6n + 5})\}^{12}\notag\\
&= q(1 - q)^{12}(1 - q^{5})^{12}(1 - q^{7})^{12}(1 - q^{11})^{12}\dots\notag\\
&= q(1 - 12q + 66q^{2} - 220q^{3} + 495q^{4} - 792q^{5} + \cdots)(1 - 12q^{5} + \cdots)\cdots\notag\\
&= q(1 - 12q + 66q^{2} - 220q^{3} + 495q^{4} - 804q^{5} + \cdots)\notag\\
&= q - 12q^{2} + 66q^{3} - 220q^{4} + 495q^{5} - 804q^{6} + \cdots\notag
\end{align}
So the last exponent in your result should be $12$ instead of $-12$. Luckily all of the steps require only basic algebraic manipulation and there is no need to invoke any non-trivial result from the theory of modular forms.

Comment: @R.A.: We have $(1 - q^{n})$ in numerator and $(1 - q^{2n})$ in denominator. So in numerator we have factors with powers of $q$ as $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots$ and in denominator powers of $q$ are $2, 4, 6, 8,\ldots$. Thus all the even powers of numerator get cancelled by denominator and what is left is only the odd powers in numerator leading to $(1 - q^{2n - 1})$. Same kind of cancellation happens with $(1 - q^{6n})$ and $(1 - q^{3n})$ (i.e. only powers with odd multiples of $3$ are left leading to $(1 - q^{3(2n - 1)})$. There can be typos in papers too. Not a big deal here.

Comment: @R.A.: BTW thanks for Beukers paper. He is an authority in the topic of irrationality. I had read his ealier papers on irrationality of $\zeta(2), \zeta(3)$ See http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/10/irrationality-of-zeta-2-and-zeta-3-part-1.html

Comment: @R.A.: I checked Beukers paper for the use of this formula. In one place he writes the product from $n = 0$ and in other place he uses $n = 1$ (page 6). So that is another instance of typo. I don't think the conclusion of the paper is crucially dependent on whether the exponent is $12$ or $-12$ but definitely I am not expert in the complicated theory of modular forms to confirm this. I can only say that my calculation in the answer is correct.

Comment: @R.A.: There is no formula to get the series expansion, but it is possible to calculate a few terms by hand. I will post first few terms of series in few minutes in the answer itself.

Comment: @R.A.: It should be easy to prove via transformation formula for $\eta$ function. But if you are having some issue in doing this, please ask another question on this website. I will try to provide an answer.